# how can i solve AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, django

**python manage.py migrate**

```
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 162, in handle
    self.stdout.write(self.style.MIGRATE_HEADING("Operations to perform:"))
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 145, in write
    self._out.write(style_func(msg))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

please can anyone help out with this error.
it popup anytime i try to use manage.py. anyone please

Answer (score 0):

You can go to *Migrations* folder and delete all the files other then **init**.py

and then run the

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem (Python 3.7 and django 1.10). Turns out the problem was that it was running on the bash (from git bash). I guess it errors trying to get stdout.

It works using Windows's command prompt.